# Ansible - get input from user each iteration

Tags: automation, ansible, active-directory

I'm trying to add users to a Windows AD through Ansible and for that I need to prompt the user for the new users' information (username, password and AD groups).

This is my current playbook but this is prompting an error beacuse apparently I cant use *vars_prompt* inside a task. So what I want to know is: How can I do loop where the user inputs new information each iteration.

Thanks

```
 vars_prompt:
    - name: num_loops
      prompt: Enter number of users you want to add
      private: no

  tasks:
    - name: create local Users

      loop: "{{ range(1, num_loops|int + 1) | list }}"
      vars_prompt:
        - name: wu_group
          prompt: "Enter the user's group"
          private: no
          
        - name: wu_username
          prompt: "Enter the username for user {{ item }}"
          private: no
        - name: wu_password
          prompt: "Enter the password for user {{ item }}"
          private: yes

      ansible.windows.win_user:
        name: "{{ wu_username }}"
        password: "{{ wu_password }}"
        groups: "{{ wu_group }}"
        update_password: on_create
        password_expired: true
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html. Meanwhile, note that this is not really an intended use for ansible. You might consider passing a list of users in a file as an extra var on the command line which would be more appropriate in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the users' names and passwords in the loop

```yaml
    - pause:
        prompt: "Enter group"
      register: out_group

    - pause:
        prompt: "{{ item }}. Enter user,password"
      register: out_users
      loop: "{{ range(1, num_loops|int + 1) | list }}"
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
  wu_group: "{{ out_group.user_input }}"
  wu_users: "{{ out_users.results|map(attribute='user_input')|
                                  map('split', ',') }}
```

gives, for example

```yaml
  wu_group: my_group
  wu_users:
    - [alice, '123']
    - [bob, '456']
    - [carol, '789']
```

---

Example of the task (not tested)

```yaml
    - ansible.windows.win_user:
        name: "{{ item.0 }}"
        password: "{{ item.1 }}"
        groups: "{{ wu_group }}"
        update_password: on_create
        password_expired: true
      loop: "{{ wu_users }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_prompt:

    - name: num_loops
      prompt: Enter number of users you want to add
      private: no

  vars:

    wu_group: "{{ out_group.user_input }}"
    wu_users: "{{ out_users.results|map(attribute='user_input')|
                                    map('split', ',') }}"
  tasks:

    - pause:
        prompt: "Enter group"
      register: out_group

    - pause:
        prompt: "{{ item }}. Enter user,password"
      register: out_users
      loop: "{{ range(1, num_loops|int + 1) | list }}"

    - debug:
        var: wu_group
    - debug:
        var: wu_users|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% filter from_yaml|to_yaml %}
          group: {{ wu_group }}
          users:
          {% for i in wu_users %}
            - {name: {{ i.0 }}, pswd: {{ i.1 }}}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 
Enter number of users you want to add: 3

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [pause] **********************************************************************************
[pause]
Enter group:
my_group^Mok: [localhost]

TASK [pause] **********************************************************************************
[pause]
1. Enter user,password:
alice,123^Mok: [localhost] => (item=1)
[pause]
2. Enter user,password:
bob,456^Mok: [localhost] => (item=2)
[pause]
3. Enter user,password:
carol,789^Mok: [localhost] => (item=3)

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  wu_group: my_group

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  wu_users|to_yaml: |-
    - [alice, '123']
    - [bob, '456']
    - [carol, '789']

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    group: my_group
    users:
    - {name: alice, pswd: 123}
    - {name: bob, pswd: 456}
    - {name: carol, pswd: 789}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: That's great, now I have a loop where I can prompt multiple inputs. But now how can I add that information to the ansible.windows.win_user function? Where in the loop do I add it?

Comment: I added the example.